# Problem finding indexes of items in a list

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find indexes of items in a list.
For example number 0 in a list of numbers.
With this code I have found index of zeros only when there one zero in the list.
When zeros are two or more, the second index doesn't get correct.
Isn't method IndexOf() the correct one to use?
How can I find all the indexes of an item, not only the first?
Thanks

```
var zerosInList = list.FindAll(x => x == 0);
            
if (zerosInList.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in zerosInList) //finding indexes of zeros
        {
            indexes.Add(list.IndexOf(item));
            Console.Write("found zero in position: "); PrintList(indexes);
        }
```

Comment: [Returns the zero-based index of the **first occurrence** of a value in the List<T> or in a portion of it.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @Liam what about the others occurrences?

Answer (score 1):

The `List<T>.IndexOf` compares elements using the default equality comparer of `T`. For integers, it uses value equality. All zeros in your `zerosInList` collection are considered to be the same. In other words, the "second zero" or "third zero" in your `foreach` loop is considered no different than the "first zero", therefore the `IndexOf` method always returns the index of the first `0` it encounters, not *the particular zero* that's the subject of the foreach loop's current iteration.

You can make a collection of all the zero's indexes in your original list this way:

```
var indexesOfZeros = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    if (list[i] == 0)
    {
        indexesOfZeros.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IndexOf method in C# searches one string for another. It returns the index of the string part, if one is found.

But you can try this:

```
    for(int i=0;i<yourFirstList.Count;i++) 
    //yourFirstList is the list with all the numbers
    {
           if(yourFirstList.ElementAt(i).value==0){
              indexes.Add(i);
            }
        
    }
    Console.Write("found zero in position: "); PrintList(indexes);
```

Comment: _"IndexOf method in C# searches one string for another_" - that's only the case if the list is a list of strings, which has nothing to do with the question here. The `yourFirstList.ElementAt(i).value` part is also only valid for elements which expose a `value` property, which isn't the case with a list of integers, nor list of strings for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

[List.FindAll method returns items that match your requisite](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findall?view=net-6.0), not their index. I mean if you have lets say

```
list[0] = 0;
list[1] = 4;
list[2] = 0;
```

and apply `FindAll( x => x == 0);` to list, you get a list which contains 2 zero values, and I think you expect indexes to contain 0 and 2 in this case. You could use `.IndexOf()` to accomplish your task, iterating through your items until you get a -1:

```
int indexOfItem = 0;
while(indexOfItem != -1 && indexOfItem < list.Count) {
    indexOfItem = list.IndexOf(0, indexOfItem);
    if (indexOfItem != -1) {
       indexes.Add(indexOfItem);
       indexOfItem++;
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Lambdas :D

```
        List<int> indexes = list.Select((item, index) => 
                item == 0 ? index : -1
            ).Where(i => i != -1).ToList();
        Console.Write("found zero in position: "); PrintList(indexes);
```

Comment: If you wanna make it even prettier, there's no need for the curly braces and `return` in the first lambda!

Comment: @Orion you're right, problems of copy paste  from a more complex piece of code :P

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following Linq expression :

```
List<int> zeroList = intList.Select((val,idx) => new {val,idx})
                      .Where(t => t.val == 0)
                      .Select(pp => pp.idx).ToList();
```

the first creates an anonymous type containing the original value & offset, the where clause filters out all instances where the value is 0 & the final select returns the index in the original list.